# Prev/Next node navigation with a thumbnail in a full node

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I've been trying to figure this out and make it work, but as I'm not a programmer, just a designer with limited coding knowledge I've been hitting a wall on this one.

I'm making my own photo gallery and I would like to display two previous or next images as linked thumbnails. I've found this script that works and shows textual links, but don't know how to adapt it to my needs.

**template.php**

```
<?php
function dad_prev_next($current_node = NULL, $op = 'p') {
    if ($op == 'p') {
        $sql_op = '<';
        $order = 'DESC';
    } elseif ($op == 'n') {
        $sql_op = '>';
        $order = 'ASC';
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }

    $output = NULL;

    $sql = "SELECT n.nid, n.title
             FROM {node} n
             WHERE n.nid $sql_op :nid
             AND type IN ('photos')
             AND status = 1
             ORDER BY nid $order
             LIMIT 1";
    $result = db_query($sql, array(':nid' => $current_node -> nid));
    foreach ($result as $data) {
    }
    if (isset($data)) {            


        if ($op == 'n')            
            return l("Next", "node/$data->nid", array('html' => TRUE));
        else if ($op == 'p')
            return l("Previous", "node/$data->nid", array('html' => TRUE));
    }
}
?>
```

**node.tpl.php**

```
<?php print dad_prev_next($node,'p') . " / " . dad_prev_next($node,'n'); ?>
```

## Working example

This one shows two previous/next images as it was designed

**template.php**

```
function dad_prev_next($nid = NULL, $op = 'p', $start = 0) {
    if ($op == 'p') {
        $sql_op = '>';
        $order = 'ASC';
    }
    elseif ($op == 'n') {
        $sql_op = '<';
        $order = 'DESC';
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }

    $output = '';

    // your node must have an image type field
    // let's say it's name is IMAGEFIELD
    // select from node table
    $query = db_select('node', 'n');
    // join node table with image field table
    $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_photo', 'i', 'i.entity_id = n.nid');
    // join file managed table where all data about managed files stored
    $query->leftJoin('file_managed', 'f', 'f.fid = i.field_photo_fid');
    $query
        // select nid and title from node
        ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
        // select uri from file_managed (image path)
        ->fields('f', array('uri'))
        // select image alt and title
        ->fields('i', array('field_photo_alt', 'field_photo_title'))
        // where nid "greater than"/"lower than" our current node nid
        ->condition('n.nid', $nid, $sql_op)
        // where node type in array('your content types')
        ->condition('n.type', array('photos'), 'IN')
        // where node is published
        ->condition('n.status', 1)
        // where requested node has image to display (if you want thumbnail)
        ->condition('f.uri', '', '!=')
        // order by nid
        ->orderBy('n.nid', $order)
        // limit result to 1
        ->range($start, 1);     

    // make query
    $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

    foreach ($result as $node) {
        // theme your thumbnail image
        $variables = array(
            // default image style name `thumbnail`
            // you can use your own by following
            // admin/config/media/image-styles on your site
            'style_name' => 'square_small',
            'path' => $node->uri,
            'alt' => $node->field_photo_alt,
            'title' => $node->field_photo_title
        );
        $image = theme('image_style', $variables);

        $options = array(
            'html' => TRUE,
            'attributes' => array(
                'title' => $node->title
            )
        );
        $output = l($image, "node/{$node->nid}", $options);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

**node.tpl.php**

```
<?php print dad_prev_next($node->nid, 'p', 1); ?>
<?php print dad_prev_next($node->nid, 'p', 0); ?>
<?php print dad_prev_next($node->nid, 'n', 0); ?>
<?php print dad_prev_next($node->nid, 'n', 1); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**template.php**

```php
function dad_prev_next($nid = NULL, $op = 'p', $qty = 1) {
    if ($op == 'p') {
        $sql_op = '<';
        $order = 'DESC';
    }
    elseif ($op == 'n') {
        $sql_op = '>';
        $order = 'ASC';
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }

    $output = '';

    // your node must have an image type field
    // let's say it's name is IMAGEFIELD
    // select from node table
    $query = db_select('node', 'n');
    // join node table with image field table
    $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_IMAGEFIELD', 'i', 'i.entity_id = n.nid');
    // join file managed table where all data about managed files stored
    $query->leftJoin('file_managed', 'f', 'f.fid = i.field_IMAGEFIELD_fid');
    $query
        // select nid and title from node
        ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
        // select uri from file_managed (image path)
        ->fields('f', array('uri'))
        // select image alt and title
        ->fields('i', array('field_IMAGEFIELD_alt', 'field_IMAGEFIELD_title'))
        // where nid "greater than"/"lower than" our current node nid
        ->condition('n.nid', $nid, $sql_op)
        // where node type in array('your content types')
        ->condition('n.type', array('photos'), 'IN')
        // where node is published
        ->condition('n.status', 1)
        // where requested node has image to display (if you want thumbnail)
        ->condition('f.uri', '', '!=')
        // order by nid
        ->orderBy('n.nid', $order)
        // limit result to $qty
        ->range(0, $qty);

    // make query
    $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

    foreach ($result as $node) {
        // theme your thumbnail image
        $variables = array(
            // default image style name `thumbnail`
            // you can use your own by following
            // admin/config/media/image-styles on your site
            'style_name' => 'thumbnail',
            'path' => $node->uri,
            'alt' => $node->field_IMAGEFIELD_alt,
            'title' => $node->field_IMAGEFIELD_title
        );
        $image = theme('image_style', $variables);

        $options = array(
            'html' => TRUE,
            'attributes' => array(
                'title' => $node->title
            )
        );
        $output = l($image, "node/{$node->nid}", $options);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

**node.tpl.php**

```php
<?php print dad_prev_next($node->nid, 'p', 2); ?>
<?php print dad_prev_next($node->nid, 'n', 2); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks it works and it's nerve saver. With little help from my brother I've managed to modify script so it follows my design to show two previous/next photos. Hope it will be helpful to others as well.

Comment: I modified your code. There's no need to call for it 2 times for each node, you have just to increase the limit on nodes. Pay attention to `$qty` variable instead of `start` which you had and to `node.tpl.php`. Hope it'll be better for you ;]

Comment: Hm... I don't see the modification.

Comment: I made changes in your text, but it seems like it wasn't been applied.  Check out my updated answer.

Comment: @VladStratulat I have posted a question related to your code, would you mind checking it out? Thank you in advance! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120363/how-to-change-results-ordering-for-mysql-query