# How to change results ordering for MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to get the previous and next node link/thumbnail for my pages and order the results according to their titles or file URIs or filenames...

The code is querying the database and outputting previous and next node links according to node IDs (nid, n.nid). I want to order the results according to either node title (title, n.title), filename (filename, f.filename), or even file URI (uri, f.uri).

However, when I change this line:

```
->orderBy('n.nid', $order)
```

to:

```
->orderBy('n.title', $order)
```

it won't work. The only difference is that it slightly changes the order if you move from the last page in one image gallery to another, but otherwise inside of the galleries everything is the same. The problem is if you have one gallery and decide to insert a new image after a while. Node ID is now totally different from the others and this code doesn't pick it up.

I have also tried with changing other parts where `nid` shows up, but it's not working.
I suppose that it's something trivial for someone who understands MySQL and PHP better, but I'm stuck with it for hours and would appreciate any help.

Here is the whole code (from Vlad Stratulat, originally found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8914912/637548)):

Template.php

```
function dad_prev_next($nid = NULL, $op = 'p', $start = 0) {
if ($op == 'p') {
    $sql_op = '>';
    $order = 'ASC';
}
elseif ($op == 'n') {
    $sql_op = '<';
    $order = 'DESC';
}
else {
    return NULL;
}

$output = '';

// your node must have an image type field
// let's say it's name is IMAGEFIELD
// select from node table
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
// join node table with image field table
$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_IMAGEFIELD', 'i', 'i.entity_id = n.nid');
// join file managed table where all data about managed files stored
$query->leftJoin('file_managed', 'f', 'f.fid = i.field_IMAGEFIELD_fid');
$query
    // select nid and title from node
    ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
    // select uri from file_managed (image path)
    ->fields('f', array('uri'))
    // select image alt and title
    ->fields('i', array('field_IMAGEFIELD_alt', 'field_IMAGEFIELD_title'))
    // where nid "greater than"/"lower than" our current node nid
    ->condition('n.nid', $nid, $sql_op)
    // where node type in array('your content types')
    ->condition('n.type', array('PHOTOS'), 'IN')
    // where node is published
    ->condition('n.status', 1)
    // where requested node has image to display (if you want thumbnail)
    ->condition('f.uri', '', '!=')
    // order by nid
    ->orderBy('n.nid', $order)
    // limit result to 1
    ->range($start, 1);     

// make query
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

foreach ($result as $node) {
    // theme your thumbnail image
    $variables = array(
        // default image style name `thumbnail`
        // you can use your own by following
        // admin/config/media/image-styles on your site
        'style_name' => 'thumbnail',
        'path' => $node->uri,
        'alt' => $node->field_IMAGEFIELD_alt,
        'title' => $node->field_IMAGEFIELD_title
    );
    $image = theme('image_style', $variables);

    $options = array(
        'html' => TRUE,
        'attributes' => array(
            'title' => $node->title
        )
    );
    $output = l($image, "node/{$node->nid}", $options);
}

return $output;
}
```

Node.tpl.php

```
<?php print dad_prev_next($node->nid, 'p', 0); ?>
<?php print dad_prev_next($node->nid, 'n', 0); ?>
```

EDIT 2:

Trying to use strcmp function:

```
function dad_prev_next($title = NULL, $op = 'p', $start = 0) {
if ($op == 'p') {
    $strcmp = '1';
    $order = 'ASC';
}
elseif ($op == 'n') {
    $strcmp = '2';
    $order = 'DESC';
}
else {
    return NULL;
}

$output = '';

// your node must have an image type field
// let's say it's name is IMAGEFIELD
// select from node table
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
// join node table with image field table
$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_IMAGEFIELD', 'i', 'i.entity_id = n.nid');
// join file managed table where all data about managed files stored
$query->leftJoin('file_managed', 'f', 'f.fid = i.field_IMAGEFIELD_fid');
$query
    // select nid and title from node
    ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
    // select uri from file_managed (image path)
    ->fields('f', array('uri'))
    // select image alt and title
    ->fields('i', array('field_IMAGEFIELD_alt', 'field_IMAGEFIELD_title'))
    // where node type in array('your content types')
    ->condition('n.type', array('PHOTOS'), 'IN')
    // where node is published
    ->condition('n.status', 1)
    // where requested node has image to display (if you want thumbnail)
    ->condition('f.uri', '', '!=')
    // order by nid
    ->orderBy('n.title', $order)
    // limit result to 1
    ->range($start, 1);     

// make query
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

foreach ($result as $node) {
    // theme your thumbnail image
    $variables = array(
        // default image style name `thumbnail`
        // you can use your own by following
        // admin/config/media/image-styles on your site
        'style_name' => 'thumbnail',
        'path' => $node->uri,
        'alt' => $node->field_IMAGEFIELD_alt,
        'title' => $node->field_IMAGEFIELD_title
    );
    $image = theme('image_style', $variables);

    $options = array(
        'html' => TRUE,
        'attributes' => array(
            'title' => $node->title
        )
    );
    $output = l($image, "node/{$node->nid}", $options);
}

return $output;
}
```

There are no errors logged now, but there are always same photos displayed - 2 of the first ones and 2 of the last ones in the alphabetical list.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `->condition('n.nid', $nid, $strcmp)`? It wont work in any case because third parameter for `->condition()` could be `>`, `<`, `=`, `<>`, `>=`, `<=`, `IN`, 'NOT IN',  etc.

Comment: @VladStratulat OK, thanks for the info. As I said, I'm a programming newbie. But one thing I don't get here - if it is a text string with some numbers only (E. G. "Title number 2"), why do I compare it with bigger/smaller than characters? Shouldn't it be something with the alphabet? If I can use `> <`, then why do I have to change anything at all except `->condition('n.nid', $nid, $sql_op)` to `->condition('n.title', $title, $sql_op)`and use `->orderBy('n.title', $order)`? And that didn't work unfortunately...

Comment: In your case `->condition('n.nid', $nid, $strcmp)` is useless. If you just want to order by title, just remove this condition from your query and `->orderBy('n.title', $order)` will do it's job.

Comment: @VladStratulat That would be great. I have removed that line (you can check my new edit), but now it's outputting always the same photos - 2 of the first ones and 2 of the last ones in the alphabet. However, there are no errors now, so I suppose it's close to the solution, with something easy that I'm missing. I have also tried with using your original code and removing that line (with adding title instead of nid) and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting by n.title, but then your first condition is looking for an n.nid greater than/lower than $nid.  This makes no sense, and results in a semi-random selection.  I suggest when sorting by title you change the condition to something n.title  $node->title, and it would work.

Comment: You are right. I did change `->condition('n.nid', $nid, $sql_op)` to `->condition('n.title', $title, $sql_op)`, but it didn't work. My guess is that titles can't use `$sql_op`, because it looks for "greater/lower than". But, what would be the right expression for something that you order alphabetically?

Comment: I think the STRCMP function will do what you need:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp

Comment: Thank you, that definitely seems to be what I need! I have edited my question with the changed code. There is an error logged, but I'm not sure what exactly I need to change additionally. It just lists all of the specified parameters from the template.php

Comment: You're setting $strcmp to 1 or 2, and that gets put into the query.  You're never actually using the STRCMP() function in your query.  Look for "n.title 2
:db_condition_placeholder_0" in the query error.  The 2 comes from your $strcmp variable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That seems like I should rewrite the whole "dad_prev_next" function, which definitely seems too hard, considering that I never wrote did anything serious in php. Could you try to explain it more in detail so that I can accept your answer?

Comment: Sorry, accepting the answer is not worth me taking the time to write the code for you.  If you don't know much PHP, I suggest you try the views module.

Comment: Unfortunately Views module isn't context aware in such a way, unless you always keep the same address and use the pager, which is mostly pointless. Thanks anyway!